# How do I figure out what's holding a lock and blocking my Java thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, wildfly, cpu-usage

I'm using Wildfly 11 with Java 8 on Amazon Linux.  We're troubleshooting a high CPU utilization issue and have the Wildfly CLI tool at our disposal.  I noticed some of our Java threads have been running for quite awhile and wanted to figure out why.  I found the ID of one thread and checked its status ...

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /core-service=platform-mbean/type=threading/:get-thread-infos (ids=[2L])
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [{
        "thread-id" => 2L,
        "thread-name" => "Reference Handler",
        "thread-state" => "WAITING",
        "blocked-time" => -1L,
        "blocked-count" => 48628L,
        "waited-time" => -1L,
        "waited-count" => 44877L,
        "lock-info" => {
            "class-name" => "java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock",
            "identity-hash-code" => 926576350
        },
        "lock-name" => "java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock@373a6ede",
        "lock-owner-id" => -1L,
        "lock-owner-name" => undefined,
        "stack-trace" => [],
        "suspended" => false,
        "in-native" => false,
        "locked-monitors" => [],
        "locked-synchronizers" => []
    }]
}
```

I don't have a firm understanding of everything here but it does seem like one issue is a lock -- "class-name" => "java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock" .  Does anyone know how I can get more information about what's causing the lock?

Comment: You can also get a thread dump by entering `kill -QUIT <processid>` from the command line. FWIW, locks don't usually result in high CPU.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to change the JVM arguments? I yes you could enable remote JMX access and trigger thread- and heap-dumps remotely.

Answer (score 3):

Can you get to the box using ssh?

If you are running Java process with JDK (not JRE) that you can check the status of the threads using `jstack` utility.

If yes, you can get thread dump immediately of all the threads of the process using:

```
jstack <process_id>
```

You can save into a file using

```
jstack <process_id> > <file_name>
```

Then you can check state of the threads and thread locks in the `file_name`. You may figure out what threads are blocked and what locks they are holding.

`jstack` command doesn't stop the process. It's safe to run it on a running process.

At least I will start with this simple approach for any blocked Java application.

Comment: Although I can get to the box using SSH, I don't have jstack on the box.  We only have a JRE and the Wildfly CLI tool at our disposal (and default Amazon Linux tools).

Comment: Oh, sorry for that :(